# Regex Positive or Negative Lookbehinds?

Tags: .net, regex

I'm always getting confused about how to properly use positive and negative look-behinds.  I have searched the internet and find most examples confusing.  I was wondering if somebody could help me.

I was wondering that if I had a regex like the following:

```
StartHere(?<result>.+?)StopHere
```

then everything between the first instance of "StartHere" and first instance of "StopHere" will be parsed out parsed out.  However if I have multiple "StartHere" in the document like the following:

```
StartHere RandomTextAndOtherCharacters StartHere TextIWantToParse PleastStopHere
```

if I use the above regex would parse "RandomTextAndOtherCharacters StartHere TextIWantToParse".

Is there a way to only parse out "TextIWantToParse" the information between the closet "StartHere" and "StopHere"?  I know the ? in the .+? makes it lazy, but is it possible to do something like that but looking behind?  Let me know if my explanation is confusing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your string is analysed from left to right. One trick to obtain what you want:

```
StartHere((?>[^S]+|S(?!tartHere|topHere))*)StopHere
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 (?i)(?!.*(starthere))(?<=(starthere)).*(?=(stophere))
```

Below is negative lookahead to make sure what is captured does not contain `starthere`, this will make sure it uses the closest `starthere` to `stophere`

```
(?!.*(starthere))
```

Then you have your positive lookbehind and positive lookahead with a `.*` in the middle

Comment: This is going to have problem if there are multiple valid pairs of `starthere` and `stophere` on the same line, and all of them must be captured.

Comment: Oh i see what your saying! I was under the impression there would only be one

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
StartHere((?:(?!StartHere|StopHere).)+)StopHere
```

`(?!StartHere|StopHere).` means before we match a character, we will check if there is `StartHere` or `StopHere` right ahead. The repetition will be stopped once `StartHere` or `StopHere` is encountered. This ensures that the text matched is between the left-most, closest pairs of `StartHere`/`StopHere`.

This is the cleanest solution in term of code clarity. However, it will do useless backtracking when `StartHere` is encountered.

A small change can be made to prevent that:

```
StartHere((?>(?:(?!StartHere|StopHere).)+))StopHere
```

The *non-backtracking group* `(?>pattern)` disallows backtracking. In this case, it will disallow backtracking into the repetition, which means no more useless backtracking when `StartHere` is encountered.